# Replace ? by number

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence

[image]

This chain of numbers is making confused.Help to find the answer with explanation.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake there was 6 in the end the solution given by @ibn-e-battota satisfies for 6 in the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is

> 16.

Explanation:

> Moving forward ,around alternate segments in the chain , one sequence decreases by 1,2,3 and 4 each time, while the other increases by 2,3,4 and 5

Comment: @Ibnebatoota Your solution doesn't work for the elements 10 and 9.

Comment: Question posted have mistake there should be  6 not 9 in question. My solution satisfies 6.